# Using Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP With Origin C++11 Libraries?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to use the Matrix class that is part of Andrew Sutton's Origin C++11 Library (https://code.google.com/p/origin/) within Visual Studio.

In the past, this was impossible to do because Visual Studio's C++ compiler did not handle constexpr terms.  As proof of this, when I would attempt to run a simple program that used this library using the VS C++ v120 compiler, I would get one error:

> Error  1   error C2144: syntax error : 'bool' should be preceded by ';'    c:\origin\origin\type\traits.hpp    286 1   Matrix_Example

However, with the advent of the C++ November 2013 CTP, Visual C++ is now supposed to support constexpr.  However, when I install the new compiler and set it up to run, I now get 50+ errors with my code.

I assume that I am doing something wrong here, and that perhaps something needs to be recompiled or rebuilt.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the Origin Library to work with the Visual C++ November 2013 CTP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the CTP's implementation of the `constexpr` feature is not complete. From [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx):

> The CTP supports C++11 constexpr, except for member functions. (Another limitation is that arrays aren't supported.) Also, it doesn't support C++14's extended constexpr rules.

Looking at that file, it appears that you are indeed running into that member function limitation.